# Creating optional (not required) feature set input in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

I am creating a model where the user can specify spatial extent by interactively drawing a polygon (a Clip tool where the clip feature is a Feature Set variable). But the model will be mostly used for the entire extent of the map so I would like the user to be able to just ignore this option if they don't want to use it. However, when running the model it is required because I think the Clip tool has to have an input to run.

Is there a way around it?

Picture of my model:
[image: picture of my model]

I am not sure if it could be important for this question but once the model is done, it will be published as a geoproccessing service and later embedded in a Web Application created through ArcGIS Web App Builder as a custom widget.

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.